# :align: image without text wrapping

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

How can I align an image but without text wrapping around it? One way is to remove

```css
.figure.align-left {float: left;}
```

from CSS, but this might break other things - anything cleaner *in RST* (I'm aware of `.. raw::html`)? Example case, wrapping in Firefox:

```
Don't wrap me
-------------

.. figure:: img.png
  :align: left
  :width: 500px

or me
```

Comment: You can create a custom CSS class, then apply it in markup with the [`class` directive](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#class).

Comment: @StevePiercy How? `.. class:: .. figure::` doesn't seem to work, and `.. figure:: :class:` inserts `class=` inside of `<img` but that's wrapped and overridden by `<figure`, even with `!important`

Comment: Apologies, it is actually `rst-class` in Sphinx when the domain is Python. I'll provide a complete answer.

Comment: Use the `:figclass:` option to pass a class value to the figure element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sphinx has a special directive, `class`, that assigns a CSS class attribute to the next element. Details of how that works is in the [docutils documentation of `class`](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#class).

However in Sphinx, when the default domain contains a `class` directive, this directive will be shadowed. Therefore, Sphinx re-exports it as [`rst-class` (see note)](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/basics.html#rstclass). As a result you must use that in Python because its language uses `class`.

The following reStructuredText markup:

```
.. rst-class:: image-no-text-wrap

.. figure:: img.png
    :align: left
    :width: 500px
```

This will yield something like the following HTML:

```html
<figure class="image-no-text-wrap align-left">
<a class="reference internal image-reference" href="_images/img.png"><img alt="_images/img.png" src="_images/img.png" style="width: 500px;"></a>
</figure>
```

Finally define the CSS selector however you think best to prevent text wrapping, for example:

```css
figure.image-no-text-wrap {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: Quite verbose, guess I'll stick with `<img` -- thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The [figure directive](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#figure) provides two options to specify a class value. While :class: is passed on to the included `<image>`, :figclass: goes to the `<figure>` element:

```
.. figure:: img.png
    :align: left
    :class: image-class-value
    :figclass: figure-class-value
```